# Querying a json object with jquery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json object I am querying in jquery and having trouble using the values stored in jquery variables. Example:

```
$tops= json.tops
$color = "blue";
```

If I `console.log($tops.blue);` I get the expected result. But, if I `console.log($tops.$color);` I get `'undefined'`.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong/what the difference is?

Comment: can you post the code you already have tried?

Comment: Was `json` ever parsed? What gets returned when you type in `typeof json`?

Comment: Why would you expect `$tops.blue` to be the same as `$tops.$color`? You haven't assigned `$tops.$color`.

Comment: You probably mean `$color = 'blue'` (with quotes), and `$tops[$color]`.

Comment: @JohnBupit the code does have quotes just left them out here by mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `console.log` example, my thought is that what you are looking for is `$tops[$color]`. `$tops.$color` would look for a property of `'$color'`.

From your code sample, I think you would need `$color = 'blue'` (blue being a string), as currently it would be the value of a variable named `blue`.

Also, perhaps this would be helpful: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: I edited my question to include "", I left those out by mistake but they are in my code. I wouldnt use brackets because i"m not accessing an array

Comment: @TatianaFrank If you look at the link I included, you will see one of the uses is 'selection of properties using variables'. The array access notation treats the object as a dictionary, with property names being the keys. Essentially `obj.x == obj['x']`.

Comment: ahh that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: I was just thrown off by the fact that it works for $tops= json.tops but not the rest... Why is that by the way?

Comment: @TatianaFrank I'm not sure what you mean by "works" with regard to `$tops = json.tops`? I presume there exists a property named `tops` on the `json` object? The `.` notation will treat whatever is on the right side of it as an identifier, and look for a property with that name. So `.blue` will look for property `blue`, `.tops` will look for property `tops`, and `.$color` will look for property `$color`. At no point do the variables in scope matter for that expansion.

Comment: @TatianaFrank Also, in case it's helpful, jQuery is not relevant here - everything you're doing is just JavaScript, and the `$` means nothing special. It just happens that JavaScript does not assign any special meaning to the `$` character and it can be used inside identifiers (function/variable names).